# How to remove the last 2 numbers from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, parsing, xlrd

I am trying to take a Display Name / Keypad code from an excel document and add it into my companies website. My problem is when I parse the data from the excel document, the document will show 4240, but when it goes to add it into the website it picks it up at 4240.0. How can I remove the ".0" when I parse the data?

This is the code I currently have, the only problem with this is for some reason it will not picking up the "0" if it is in the front or end of a code.

For example, if the code is 0420, it only picks up 42 and doesn't apply the leading and ending 0. I tried changing the excel format to text that way it doesn't pick it up as a number but that didn't help either.
I think the best method would be to remove the last 2 pieces of information with index?

```
def addCodesA():
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    for y in range(sheet.nrows):
        names = []
        codes = []
        convertedcodes = []
        names.append(str(sheet.cell_value(y, 0)))
        codes.append(str(sheet.cell_value(y, 1)))
        for strippedcode in codes:
            convertedcodes.append(strippedcode.strip('.0'))
            print(names)
            print(codes)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="device_keypad_relay"][@value="0"]').click()
            time.sleep(1)
            codeadd = driver.find_element_by_name('keypad_code_1')
            nameadd = driver.find_element_by_name('keypad_code_1_display')
            codeadd.clear()
            nameadd.clear()
            codeadd.send_keys(convertedcodes) 
            nameadd.send_keys(names)
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-form-end').send_keys(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(6)
            driver.get(customercodes)
```

Comment: I don't have any example data to work from, but it seems you are reading floats and you could convert them to int early. E.g., `codes.append(str(int(sheet.cell_value(y, 1))))`

Comment: `str.strip(str)` loops through all the characters of the string, it does not work with strings with len > 1. You can use `strippedcode.split(".0")` or `strippedcode.replace(".0", "")` or as @tdelaney sayd, `int(strippedcode)`.

Comment: codes.append(str(int(sheet.cell_value(y, 1)))) <--- this is working for removing .0 on the end of the code but it still doesn't pick up the leading 0's. for instance, 0420, it only picks up 420 and misses the leading 0. I am going to try strippedcode.split(".0") now